# Question about point-wise convergent sequence of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $$f_n(x)=n^2x(1-x^2)^n$$ be a sequence of functions on $[0,1]$.
For $x=0$ and $x=1,$ clearly $f_n(x)=0$.
Also for any $x_0$ in the open interval $(0,1)$, we have $0<1-x_0^2<1$.
Therefore $$ \lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)=0$$
for all $x \in[0,1].$
Note that $\dfrac{1}{ \sqrt{n}} \in [0,1]  \forall n\in N$ and $f_n(\dfrac{1}{ \sqrt{n}})=n^{3/2}(1-\dfrac{1}{n})^n$.  Then it seems like that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(\dfrac{1}{ \sqrt{n}})= \lim_{n \to \infty}n^{3/2}e^{-1}=\infty$$
How can be this happen?

Comment: Be careful: while $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right) = \infty$$ you can't say $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} n^{3/2} e^{-1}$$ because this means you've applied the limit to the right function only. Nevertheless, I think this shows that convergence is not uniform, only pointwise.

Comment: @MarkFantini: Thanks. It means if $f_n$ is uniformly converge this could not be happen? As you know what is the best reference book for sequence of functions?

Comment: There is no contradiction here. When you take the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(1/\sqrt{n})$, you are not only changing the function $f_n$, you are also changing the argument.

Comment: @KimJongUn: Can you explane it little bit.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but all I see is that you have a neat example that is a bit counter intuitive at first glance but there is nothing wrong with the math. Like Frank Fantini said, it just shows convergence is pointwise, not uniform.

Comment: I don't know the best reference. Most, if not all, real analysis books touch on the subject. A book which I took interest in recently is in [this page, available for free](http://classicalrealanalysis.info/com/FREE-PDF-DOWNLOADS.php), Elementary Real Analysis.

Comment: @MarkFantini $\infty$ Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a plot will help. This shows the function for $n=5,10,20$.

[image: functions]

So at any particular point, like 0.1 the values of $f_n(0.1)$ get larger as $n$ increases before they get smaller.

Convergence is clearly not uniform on the entire interval.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of not adding to the unanswered pile, I'm turning my comment into an answer.

Be careful: while

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right) = \infty$$

you can't say

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} n^{3/2} e^{-1}$$

because this means you've applied the limit to the right function only.

Regardless, this shows that the convergence is not uniform, only pointwise.